# Create 10 divs but only add color to some of them based on value from api

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create 10 divs but only add the class "green" if they are within the value of a number 0-10.

let's say the rating is 6. That means only those 6 are green while the remaining 4 are grey.

I've tried with a for Loop and if statements. But nothing really happens beside creating 6 green colored divs.

My code is far from perfect but here it is.

```
  let rating = 6;
  let stars = document.querySelector(".total-rating");

  for (let i = 0; i < rating; i++) {
    if (i <= rating) {
      let star = document.createElement("div");
      star.className = "star green";
      stars.appendChild(star);
    }
  }
```

Comment: "But nothing really happens beside creating 6 green colored divs." But isn't that what you want? Could you clarify what the expected behavior is?

Comment: I would think you'd want `i < 10`, and then `star.className = "star" + (i <= rating ? " green" : "");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 10 stars, loop 10 times. Then just add "green" to the first 6.

```
  let rating = 6;
  let stars = document.querySelector(".total-rating");

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      let star = document.createElement("div");
      star.className = "star" + (i <= rating ? " green" : "");
      stars.appendChild(star);
  }
```

Comment: That was exactly what i wanted. Much Appreciated!